# vim: copy via regex and paste

Tags: vim

I'm looking to write a vim macro (not that I know how yet) eventually, as I'm sure I can do this in vim, but I don't know the basics yet.

I want to grab the branch name (or part of it anyway - that part of the regex should be straightforward) from a git commit message, and paste it, with a colon, to the top of the file, and hopefully leave the cursor at the end of that.

So the file looks a bit like this when I start:

```
$ <-- cursor here
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch JIRA-1234-some-description-here
# Your branch is up to date with ...
```

I want to capture the `/On branch \([A-Z]*-[0-9]*\)/`, move back up to the top, paste it, and a colon, leaving the cursor after the colon, e.g.:

```
JIRA-1234: $ <-- cursor here
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch JIRA-1234-some-description-here
# Your branch is up to date with ...
```

Ideally, also leave me in insert mode there.

Comment: You maybe don't want to do this in Vim, but use the [prepare-commit-msg hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) in conjunction with a commit message template

Comment: If you do want to do it in Vim, you might prefer to ask on https://vi.stackexchange.com

Comment: I did exactly this, but with a git hook. https://github.com/lukas-reineke/dotfiles/blob/master/git/templates/hooks/prepare-commit-msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
function! MyFunction()                                                      
  g/On branch \([A-Z]*-[0-9]*\)/exe "co0 | 1s/.* \\(.*-\\d\\+\\).*/\\1:/g"
  normal $                                                                  
endfunction
```

and then map it:

```
nmap <leader>f :call MyFunction()<cr>
```

Explanation of function: the global command `g/{pat}/[cmd]` executes the command `[cmd]` on lines where pattern `{pat}` matches. You've already provided `{pat}` in your question. Then, to execute more than one command I recommend to use `exe`. Here `exe` copies the matched line to the first line (`co0`) and performs the replacement (`1s/.../\\1:/g`).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) you can use `fugitive#head()` to get the current branch name. You can probably do something like this (put in `vimrc` file):

```
augroup MyCommit
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType gitcommit call setline(1, substitute(fugitive#head(), '^\([A-Z]\+-[0-9]\+\).*', '\1: ', ''))
augroup END
```

Note: I have not tested this in anyway.